# app-location deletes query string parameters

Tags: polymer, query-string, polymer-2.x

I have a very simple polymer 2 app, which uses query query string parameters. Moving to Polymer 2.0.1 and app-location 2.0 (instead of rc and preview versions), I noticed that simply having an app-location element deletes all query string parameters from the url.

Try this url: https://api-1913.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/index.html?foo=bar, and notice how the query string is removed during loading.

Here's all the code:
index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="/my-app.html">
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app></my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

my-app.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/app-route/app-location.html">

<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>
    <app-location></app-location>

    <h1>Coin</h1>
  </template>
  <script>
    class App extends Polymer.Element{
      static get is(){return 'my-app'}

      ready(){
        super.ready()
        console.log('ready')
      }
    }
    customElements.define(App.is, App)
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Specifying `query-params` attribute to map it to a property of `App` does not change anything. Remove the `app-location` element and query string is kept.
Has anyone seen this behavior? Is there any workaround - except a rollback to a previous version?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug. You can temporarly remove the default value in iron-location element until the fix is released.

**Lines to remove**

```
value: function() {
  return {};
}
```

**Affected property**

```
   paramsObject: {
    type: Object,
    notify: true,
    value: function() {
      return {};
    }  
   },
```

Reference:
https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-location/pull/86/commits/3732e93ce2197178f76c3c2073438b9cd15096b4